# C variable initialization valgrind complains

Tags: c, variables, initialization, valgrind

I have a simple question here. I have some variable declarations as follows:

```
char long_name_VARA[]="TEST -- Gridded 450m daily Evapotranspiration (ET)";
int16 fill_PET_8day=32767;
```

Given the above valgrind complains for the char declaration as follows:

```
Invalid write of size 8
==21902==    at 0x408166: main (main.c:253)
==21902==  Location 0x7fe677840 is 0 bytes inside long_name_VARA[0]
```

and for the int16 declaration as follows:

```
==21902== Invalid write of size 2
==21902==    at 0x408178: main (main.c:226)
Location 0x7fe677420 is 0 bytes inside local var "fill_PET_8day"
```

What am i doing wrong in my declarations here?

Also can I not declare a char array like this:

```
char temp_year[5]={0}
```

Comment: What OS? How exactly are you compiling this? what flags?

Comment: Cent OS 64 bit and flags are -O3 -ansi -ggdb -DLINUX -Df2cFortran -DMEOS -DUM_PGS -DNDEBUG

Comment: The error has nothing to do with these declarations. The messages that you quoted are *supplementary* messages that provide *additional* information for an issue that was reported by valgrind *before* these messages. Post the actual **full** error message. These supplementary pieces mean nothing by themselves.

Comment: @AnT I have edited the post to include the full message

Comment: Valgrind complains when you write to those variables. The warning is caused by lines 226 and 253 in main.c

Comment: `main.c:253` - hmmm. methinks there's one helluva lot more to the code that causes this than a few declarations.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a minimal working example?  Just the variables, and a `main` that returns zero?

Comment: Could you add the local variables section of your `main` function to your post?

Answer (score 2):

The warning messages you quoted show invalid memory accesses, which happen to hit memory areas belonging to the above two variables. The variables in question are *victims* of the error, not perpetrators. The variables are not to blame here. Nothing is wrong with the above declarations. Most likely these declarations are not in any way relevant here.

The perpetrators are lines at `main.c:253` and `main.c:226`, which you haven't quoted yet. That's where your problem occurs.

A wild guess would be that you have another object declared after `fill_PET_8day` (an array?). When working with that other object, you overrun its memory boundary by ~10 bytes, thus clobbering `fill_PET_8day` and first 8 bytes of `long_name_VARA`. This is what valgrind is warning you about.

Comment: The lines I have quoted here are the ones related to lines 253 and 266. I just quoted the relevant portion here as the actual code is too long. There is however a warning message that valgrind shows: "==21902== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x7fefff578 --> 0x7fe677280
==21902==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=9995000 or greater"

Comment: @srsci: Apparently you misjudged what's relevant and what's not... BTW, are you saying that these lines actually *are* lines 253 and 266?

Comment: @srsci: Your original post shows these variables as declared together, next to each other. But the line numbers say that they are actually quite far apart... There's no way to say what's going on here without seeing more code (or piling up wild guesses).

Comment: @srsci: Looks like you could have very big stack variables, as Valgrind suggests `--max-stackframe=9995000`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the declarations aren't the issue.

Although FYI, it may be better to declare your constant string as `const`...

```
const char* long_name_VARA = "TEST -- Gridded 450m daily Evapotranspiration (ET)";
```

or even...

```
const char* const long_name_VARA = "TEST -- Gridded 450m daily Evapotranspiration (ET)";
```

This prevents the string from being modified in code, (and the pointer).

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following

```
/* test.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[8000000];
    int x;

    s[0] = '\0';
    x=5;
    printf("%s %d\n",s,x);
    return 0;
}
```

with Valgrind I get

```
$ gcc test.c
$ valgrind ./a.out
==1828== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1828== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1828== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1828== Command: ./a.out
==1828== 
==1828== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0xfff0002e0 --> 0xffe85f0d0
==1828==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=8000016 or greater
==1828== Invalid write of size 1
==1828==    at 0x400541: main (in /home/m/a.out)
==1828==  Address 0xffe85f0d0 is on thread 1's stack
==1828==  in frame #0, created by main (???)
==1828== 
==1828== Invalid write of size 8
==1828==    at 0x400566: main (in /home/m/a.out)
==1828==  Address 0xffe85f0c8 is on thread 1's stack
==1828==  in frame #0, created by main (???)
==1828== 
==1828== Invalid read of size 1
==1828==    at 0x4E81ED3: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==1828==    by 0x4E88038: printf (printf.c:33)
==1828==    by 0x40056A: main (in /home/m/a.out)
==1828==  Address 0xffe85f0d0 is on thread 1's stack
==1828==  in frame #2, created by main (???)
==1828== 
 5
==1828== Invalid read of size 8
==1828==    at 0x4E88040: printf (printf.c:37)
==1828==    by 0x40056A: main (in /home/m/a.out)
==1828==  Address 0xffe85f0c8 is on thread 1's stack
==1828==  in frame #0, created by printf (printf.c:28)
==1828== 
==1828== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0xffe85f0d0 --> 0xfff0002e0
==1828==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=8000016 or greater
==1828== 
==1828== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1828==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1828==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==1828== 
==1828== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1828== 
==1828== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1828== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I give the option Valgrind warns with I get

```
$ valgrind --max-stackframe=10000000 ./a.out
==1845== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1845== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1845== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1845== Command: ./a.out
==1845== 
 5
==1845== 
==1845== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1845==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1845==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==1845== 
==1845== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1845== 
==1845== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1845== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So the "Invalid reads/writes" are due to the large stack variable without the proper `--max-stackframe=...` option.